# Proof using Cauchy's criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove using Cauchy's criterion that the sum of the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k+1}{3k-1}\right)^k$$

converges.

I believe I have to use geometric sum to solve this but I have hit a dead end.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks tailor made for the root test.

Comment: @DougM as mentioned, I wish to use Cauchy's criterion.

Comment: @segevp Well, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cauchy criterion:

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k+1}{3k-1}\right)^k$
converges if
for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$

$\sum_\limits{k=n}^{n+p} \left(\frac{k+1}{3k-1}\right)^k < \epsilon$

for all  $p\ge 1$

$\frac 12>\frac{k+1}{3k-1}>\frac 13$ for all $k>1$

$\sum_\limits{k=n}^{n+p} \left(\frac{k+1}{3k-1}\right)^k < \sum_\limits{k=n}^{n+p} \frac 12^k = (\frac 12)^{n-1}(1- (\frac 12)^{p+1})<(\frac 12)^{n-1}$

let $N=\max(-\frac {\ln \epsilon}{\ln 2}+1,2)$

Comment: thanks champ! good answer :)

Comment: It is $p+1$ in line before the last. but (+1).

Answer (score 2):

You may easily notice that

$$ \lim_{k\to +\infty}\left(\frac{3k+3}{3k-1}\right)^k = \lim_{k\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{4}{3k-1}\right)^k = e^{4/3} $$
hence the general term of the given series behaves like $\frac{e^{4/3}}{3^k}$ and the series is convergent by asymptotic comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: that's seems to be a good start but notice I wish to use Cauchy's criterion so we need to use "epsilon" language here.

Comment: @segevp: then you just need to write $\lim_{k\to +\infty} a_k = A$ with the $\epsilon/\delta$ language.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{k\to+\infty}(u_k)^\frac 1k= $$
$$\lim_{+\infty}\frac {k+1}{3k-1}=1/3 <1$$

thus, $\sum u_k $ converges.

Answer (score 0):

The sum converge iff for all $ \epsilon>0 $ there is a natural number N such that
${\displaystyle |a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots +a_{n+p}|<\varepsilon } $ with $p>0 $ $n>N$ , it's easy to see that $\frac{k+1}{3k−1}^{k}$ is decreasing, now we can write that $ |a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots +a_{n+p}| < |pa_{n+1}|$.Now we apply the fact that $\frac{k+1}{3k−1}^{k}$ converges to $0$ , so $\forall \epsilon>0$ there's N' exist such  $|u_{n+1}|<\epsilon '$ . Note $m=max(N,N')$ Now for all $ \epsilon>0 $ there is a natural number m such that $|pa_{n+1}|<p*\epsilon'$. Conclusion : ${\displaystyle |a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\cdots +a_{n+p}|<|pa_{n+1}|<p*\epsilon'=\epsilon }  $.